# Bad performance on manually resizable popup window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a popup/slider window that can be manually resized horizontally.

My issue is the performance, dragging the window results in a slow response from the browser. While the resizing isn't laggy, it is very delayed. Ideally I want the window to keep up with the mouse position.

Any suggestion on how to fix or improve this?
Thank you in advance!

```js
  let isResizing = false;
  let startX = 0;
  let startWidth = 0;
  
  /* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px and the left margin of the page content to 250px and add a black background color to body */
  function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "500px";
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block"; // Show overlay
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)"; // Set background color
  }
  
  /* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 and the left margin of the page content to 0, and the background color of body to white */
  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none"; // Hide overlay
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white"; // Reset background color
  }
  
  document.getElementById("resizeButton").addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    isResizing = true;
    startX = event.clientX;
    startWidth = parseFloat(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("mySidenav")).width);
    // document.body.style.cursor = "grabbing"; // Change cursor to grabbed immediately upon mousedown
    document.getElementById("resizeButton").style.cursor = "grabbing"; // Change cursor to grabbed immediately upon mousedown
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', resize);
  });
  
  function resize(event) {
    if (isResizing) {
      let newWidth = startWidth - (event.clientX - startX);
      if (newWidth > 100) {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = newWidth + 'px';
      }
    }
  }
  
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
    if (isResizing) {
      isResizing = false;
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', resize);
      // document.body.style.cursor = "default"; // Change cursor back to default upon mouseup
      document.getElementById("resizeButton").style.cursor = "grab"; // Change cursor back to grab upon mouseup
    }
  });
```

```css
    /* The side navigation menu */
.sidenav {
  height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
  width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
  top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
  right: 0;
  background-color: #111; /* Black*/
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
  transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 32px 8px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */
#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

.fixedbutton {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px; 
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #c1bdbd;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fixedbutton:hover{
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.resize-button {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*cursor:grab;*/ /* Initial cursor */
  user-select: none; /* Disable text selection */
}


.resize-button:hover{
  cursor:grab;
}


.overlay {
  position: fixed; /* Sit on top of the page content */
  width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
  height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1); /* Black background with opacity */
  z-index: 0; /* Specify a stack order in case you're using a different z-index elsewhere */
  display: none; /* Initially hidden */
}

.adaIframe{
  border: unset;
  margin: 10px;
}

.section2{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.Eg{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <div id="resizeButton" class="resize-button"></div>
    </div>

      
      <div id="overlay" class="overlay" onclick="closeNav()"></div> <!-- Add overlay -->
      

      <div id="main">
        <section class="section1">
          <p>Velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque. Posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada. Tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor. Ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit. Eu augue ut lectus arcu. Eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec. Elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Est placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta. Commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla. Dictum sit amet justo donec enim diam vulputate. Pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel. Aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi tempus. Iaculis nunc sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat. Quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam. Vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt.
          </p>
          <p>Velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque. Posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada. Tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor. Ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit. Eu augue ut lectus arcu. Eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec. Elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Est placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta. Commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla. Dictum sit amet justo donec enim diam vulputate. Pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel. Aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi tempus. Iaculis nunc sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat. Quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam. Vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt.
          </p>
          <p>Fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis. Aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant. Enim facilisis gravida neque convallis. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Quis lectus nulla at volutpat diam ut. Tortor id aliquet lectus proin nibh nisl. Cursus risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada. Cursus euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem. Amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est. Integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi. Commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum. Mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui. Egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus. Ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Facilisis volutpat est velit egestas. Ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit.
          </p>
          <p>Duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt. In eu mi bibendum neque. Auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum. Non arcu risus quis varius. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere. Vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan. Sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat. Eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at. Eget arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur. Mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. Cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel turpis. Id diam vel quam elementum. Amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra.
          </p>
        </section>
        <section class="section2">  
          <div class="Eg"><h1>Example 1</h1></div>
          <div class="Eg"><h1>Example 2</h1></div>
          <div class="Eg"><h1>Example 3</h1></div>
        </section>
        
        <span class="fixedbutton" onclick="openNav()"><h3>Open</h3></span>
      </div>
    
</body>

  
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/MBanski/yr1g0x5o/2/

Comment: You know _who_ introduced that "delay"? You did - with `transition: 0.5s` on the element. While you want that transition when the popup initially opens, you don't want it any more, when the user changes the element width by dragging the handle - so you need to _remove_ it now, so that changes to the width can occur instantly, instead of being _transitioned_ over a period of half a second for every change.

Comment: @CBroe well this has made me feel very stupid! Thank you! This has solved my issue

Comment: Please don't update the title to show that the question has been answered. Please also don't add the answer in the question, please add your own answer - you'll be able to accept it get some extra reputation too.

Comment: @phuzi wasn't aware that I could answer my own question. In have edited the question text and added an answer

Answer (score 2):

FIXED: Fixed thanks to @CBroe suggestion. Fixed code:

The issue was being caused by my own code (transition: 0.5s;) which was being applied each time the slider was adjusted. I have removed the transition while the slider is open.

```js
  let isResizing = false;
  let startX = 0;
  let startWidth = 0;
  let sidenav = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
  
  /* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px and the left margin of the page content to 250px and add a black background color to body */
  function openNav() {
    sidenav.style.width = "500px";
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block"; // Show overlay
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)"; // Set background color
  }
  
  /* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 and the left margin of the page content to 0, and the background color of body to white */
  function closeNav() {
    sidenav.style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none"; // Hide overlay
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white"; // Reset background color
  }
  
  document.getElementById("resizeButton").addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    isResizing = true;
    startX = event.clientX;
    startWidth = parseFloat(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(sidenav).width);
    // Temporarily remove transition during resize
    sidenav.style.transition = 'none';
    // document.body.style.cursor = "grabbing"; // Change cursor to grabbed immediately upon mousedown
    document.getElementById("resizeButton").style.cursor = "grabbing"; // Change cursor to grabbed immediately upon mousedown
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', resize);
  });
  
  function resize(event) {
    if (isResizing) {
      let newWidth = startWidth - (event.clientX - startX);
      if (newWidth > 100) {
        sidenav.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
      }
    }
  }
  
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
    if (isResizing) {
      isResizing = false;
      // Restore transition after resize
      sidenav.style.transition = '0.5s';
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', resize);
      // document.body.style.cursor = "default"; // Change cursor back to default upon mouseup
      document.getElementById("resizeButton").style.cursor = "grab"; // Change cursor back to grab upon mouseup
    }
  });
```

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
  width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
  top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
  right: 0;
  background-color: #111; /* Black*/
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
  transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 32px 8px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */
#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

.fixedbutton {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px; 
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #c1bdbd;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fixedbutton:hover{
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.resize-button {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*cursor:grab;*/ /* Initial cursor */
  user-select: none; /* Disable text selection */
}


.resize-button:hover{
  cursor:grab;
}


.overlay {
  position: fixed; /* Sit on top of the page content */
  width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
  height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black background with opacity */
  z-index: 0; /* Specify a stack order in case you're using a different z-index elsewhere */
  display: none; /* Initially hidden */
}

.adaIframe{
  border: unset;
  margin: 10px;
}

.section2{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.Eg{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <div id="resizeButton" class="resize-button"></div>
    </div>
      
      <!-- Use any element to open the sidenav -->
      
      <div id="overlay" class="overlay" onclick="closeNav()"></div> <!-- Add overlay -->
      
      <!-- Add all page content inside this div if you want the side nav to push page content to the right (not used if you only want the sidenav to sit on top of the page -->
      <div id="main">
        <section class="section1">
          <p>Velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque. Posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada. Tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor. Ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit. Eu augue ut lectus arcu. Eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec. Elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Est placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta. Commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla. Dictum sit amet justo donec enim diam vulputate. Pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel. Aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi tempus. Iaculis nunc sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat. Quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam. Vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt.
          </p>
          <p>Velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque. Posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada. Tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor. Ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit. Eu augue ut lectus arcu. Eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec. Elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Est placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta. Commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla. Dictum sit amet justo donec enim diam vulputate. Pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel. Aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi tempus. Iaculis nunc sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat. Quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam. Vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt.
          </p>
          <p>Fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis. Aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant. Enim facilisis gravida neque convallis. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Quis lectus nulla at volutpat diam ut. Tortor id aliquet lectus proin nibh nisl. Cursus risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada. Cursus euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem. Amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est. Integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi. Commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum. Mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui. Egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus. Ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Facilisis volutpat est velit egestas. Ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit.
          </p>
          <p>Duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt. In eu mi bibendum neque. Auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum. Non arcu risus quis varius. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere. Vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan. Sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat. Eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at. Eget arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur. Mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. Cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel turpis. Id diam vel quam elementum. Amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra.
          </p>
        </section>
        <section class="section2">  
          <div class="Eg"><h1>Example 1</h1></div>
          <div class="Eg"><h1>Example 2</h1></div>
          <div class="Eg"><h1>Example 3</h1></div>
        </section>
        
        <span class="fixedbutton" onclick="openNav()"><h3>Open</h3></span>
      </div>
    
</body>

  
</html>
```